# Google Colab сокращает данные в колонках

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

При чтении файла в Google Colab через `read_csv`, в таблице отображаются первые две цифры после запятой из четырёх. Причём при выводе из датафрейма, который записан с этого файла, чисел, они читаются нормально (с 4 знаками после запятой), а в таблице всё равно показываются только 2 знака после запятой.

Вопрос: мне нужно визуальное ознакомление с данными - как настроить полное отображение (именно в Google Colab)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно, у меня по 6 знаков после запятой в колабе показывает. Но можете попробовать такую опцию:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format
```

Рецепт [подсмотрен](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20937592/8324991) на англоязычном SO.

Answer (score 1):

Формат печати вещественных чисел в notebook определяется магической инструкцией `%precision`

По умолчанию в Google Colab это `%r`

Вы можете поменять число знаков после запятой так: `%precision 6`
Это коротка форма для `%precision %.6f`

Comment: Не работает когда ставлю отдельной строкой. Библиотека lazypredict.Supervised режет это свойство и скидывает на сокращение в 2 после запятой. Как правильно применять этот код?